# SP2013 Client Peoplepicker IE11+

Tags: internet-explorer, events, sharepoint, quirks-mode

How can I use the client-side people picker from Sharepoint 2013?

I keep getting this error form `init.js`:

`Object doesn't support property or method 'attachEvent'`

I know IE11+ doesn't support the method "attachEvent" anymore but how can I use the peoplepicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little fix:

`if (typeof browseris !== 'undefined') {
    browseris.ie = false;
}`

Add this to the top of your code
It will check if it's ie, if yes it sets the identity to, let's call it "unknown".
This will allow the `init.js` to properly do the event attaching.